# SQL Server query if then logic

Tags: sql-server

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT name 
            FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases 
            WHERE name = 'db'))
THEN
    ALTER DATABASE 'db' SET RESTRICTED_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
```

Sorry for the lame question but all I want to do is if the database exist then alter it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach can be like following.

```
if db_id('db') is not null
begin
 ALTER DATABASE db SET RESTRICTED_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE; 
end
```

Note that with `ALTER DATABASE` you need to specify the db name as literal, `'db'` will not work.

Correct :  `ALTER DATABASE db SET RESTRICTED_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;`

You will get Error :  `ALTER DATABASE 'db' SET RESTRICTED_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;`

Answer (score 2):

T-Sql doesn't have a `then` keyword as part of the  `if` statement. Source https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017. Just remove the word 'then'.

Answer (score 1):

Samsam, you can try this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE name = 'db')
BEGIN
    SELECT 'Database Name already Exist' AS Message
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    ALTER DATABASE 'db' SET RESTRICTED_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE; 
END
```

**Reference:**

- [Alter table if exists or create if doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16837134/alter-table-if-exists-or-create-if-doesnt)
- http://sqlserverplanet.com/dba/check-if-database-exists