# Rename MySQL table name safely in Flyway script

Tags: mysql, sql, flyway

I'm going to rename a MySQL 8.0 table via Flyway SQL script:

```
RENAME TABLE aaa TO bbb;
```

and it's supposed to be run on env many times - but such the script is not idempotent, trying to run it second time I catch an error:

```
SQL State  : 42S01
Error Code : 1050
Message    : Table 'bbb' already exists
Location   : db/migration/V7__blabla.sql (/usr/local/...)
Line       : 1
Statement  : RENAME TABLE aaa TO bbb
```

Could someone suggest please how to handle it?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## `IF EXISTS`

Use the `IF EXISTS` clause. The command ceases, with no effect, if no such table is found.

```sql
ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS name
RENAME TO new_name 
;
```

This [works in Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html). For MySQL, see [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16837134/642706).

Comment: Seems like it's not a valid syntax for MySQL unfortunately... Thank you for your quick response!

Comment: The principle is correct, just a minor syntax tweak. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16837134/alter-table-if-exists-or-create-if-doesnt

Answer (score 1):

you should think about multiple cases

1. Renaming a table referenced by a view
2. Renaming a table referenced by a stored procedure
3. Renaming a table that has foreign keys referenced to

this link will help users safely rename your table.
https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-rename-table/